# Angularjs ng-repeat with $resource

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie with angularjs

I want get data with $resource whitch repeat on html

but there is  the error show

"Expected ngRepeat in form of '*item* in *collection*' but got 'user'"

code

```
<dd ng-repeat= user in User.users>
   <input type="radio" value= "{{user.user.userId}}" />
  {{user.user.userUsername}}
</dd>



$scope.User= {'user': userService.query()};
```

please help

return data

```
User:  { 
  user: 
  [  { 
       userId: 1
       userName: User1
       userUsername: user1
       userPassword: 123456
       userSex: male
       userBirthday: 1999-01-01
       userStatus: 1
       roleId: 1
       roleModel:  {  } 
      } ,  
      { 
       userId: 2
       userName: User2
       userUsername: user2
       userPassword: 123456
       userSex: female
       userBirthday: 1888-01-01
       userStatus: 1
       roleId: 1
       roleModel:  {  } 
   }  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in User.user">
    <input type="radio" value= "{{user.userId}}" />
    {{user.userUsername}}
</div>
```

Comment: Actually it should be User.user and not users.

Comment: What data does your service return?

Comment: orginal data from service like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if your  userService.query() return collection of objects.

```
<dd ng-repeat= "user in User.users">
   <input type="radio" value= "{{user.userId}}" />
  {{user.userUsername}}
</dd>



$scope.User= {'user': userService.query()};
```